# Receiving abnormal amount of Facebook friend requests from real people with mutual friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

During the past week, I have been receiving numerous friend requests per day. They're all real people with whom I share mutual friends, however, this has never happened. It's odd because I'm getting multiple per day when this usually would only happen to me once every few months or so. Is there a reason so many *real* people I have secondhand connections to would all start adding me?

Answer (score 1):

It could just be coincidence.

Facebook changes things around all the time. They may be doing something right now to push "possible connections" to people and people are responding to it. I've not noticed anything myself, but that means nothing. (Facebook is constantly doing A/B testing, it may be an iPhone and/or Android only thing, and so on.)

Probably the only people who can say for sure are at Facebook, so all we can do is speculate.

Comment: That's possible. Facebook loves to experiment with us. However, I should have mentioned before that it's only males adding me. I haven't gotten a single friend request from a female. Also, I had three requests in my notifications a few days ago. I went a day and a half without deleting or accepting them and during that time I didn't get any more... But as soon as I accepted or deleted them, I got another request within the hour.