# Why am I suddenly receiving so many Facebook friend requests?

Tags: facebook-friend-request

Although I have a Facebook account, I have not told any of my friends or family members yet. I have not made any friend requests yet.

My privacy setting for Who can contact me? Who can send you friend requests? is Friends of Friends.

For the past few weeks I have suddenly been receiving friend requests from total strangers. I have no idea who these people are or why they are attempting to contact me. Although I delete all the requests, I am feeling somewhat overwhelmed and am considering deleting my account.

Why might this be happening? How can I stop this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving abnormal amount of Facebook friend requests from real people with mutual friends](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106616/receiving-abnormal-amount-of-facebook-friend-requests-from-real-people-with-mutu)

Comment: @pnuts: I agree, but sometimes even you have not told anyone, Facebook suggests your name to other users based on your location, interests, activities etc.. And other people who have interest in increasing their network start sending friend request. We exactly don't know. Sometimes Facebook pick contacts from email address also.